# How can I select the last edited version of a post in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table structure:

```
// posts
+----+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+
| id |            body             | edited_id | date_time  |
+----+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | post1                       | NULL      | 1464136759 |
| 2  | post2                       | NULL      | 1464136760 | 
| 3  | post2     edited            | 2         | 1464136761 | 
| 4  | post2     eduted again      | 2         | 1464136762 | 
+----+-----------------------------+-----------+------------+
```

As you can see, table above keeps both posts and their edition version. Currently I'm selecting posts like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN (1,2) ORDER BY date_time ASC;
```

**Current output:**

```
| 1  | a question                  | NULL      | 1464136759 |
| 2  | my answer                   | NULL      | 1464136760 |
```

**Expected output:**

```
| 1  | a question                  | NULL      | 1464136759 |
| 4  | my answer eduted again      | 2         | 1464136762 |
```

see? The post `id = 2` has two edition versions, and I always need to select be biggest one (according to `date_time`). How can I do that?

Comment: how you know that id2 is answer to question in id1?

Comment: The problem is when "4" is edited.  You have a graph problem and MySQL has basically no support for hierarchical or recursive queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff According to my current policies, edited rows won't be edit again. All edition versions point to the original post.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well, v8.0 is now in production status, so this is not strictly true any longer (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive). Obviously, this requires an upgrade to v8.0

Comment: @MartinAJ in this case it is the traditional get record with maximum value within a group question, which has already been asked and answered here on SO.

Comment: @Shadow Can you please rephrase "... get record with maximum value within a group question ..."

Comment: @MartinAJ I gave you a link to a duplicate topic, which not only contains various solutions, but the most upvoted ones also provide explanations. This way you can learn how to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rows won't be edited, then you can use:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where (p.id in (1, 2) or p.edited_id in (1, 2)) and
      p.id = (select p2.id
              from posts p2
              where p.id in (p2.id, p2.edited_id)
              order by date_time desc
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: emm, either `or` has a bigger priority or `and` ?